# Error : the type or namespace name "type" could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

This error occours when i get the type from assembly

```
 var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Projet.Module01.Domain");
 Type type = assembly.GetType(tipoCapaLoteNome);
 var newObject = DictionaryToObject<type>(myGenericObject);
```

Comment: Issue with Line 3. You should use the Class or Type name instead of object.

Comment: `type` is an object, not a `Type`. You can't build a generic like that, you would have to construct it through reflection to do it that way.

Comment: generics requires compile time knowledge of the data type.